# Mount APFS Volume to /Users with the Disk Utility during the installation

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I’m trying during the installation from MacOS High Sierra to separate the system and user data. I splitted the SSD with Disk Utility, but I can’t mount the second APFS Volume to /Users with the Disk Utility. Is that possible at this stage?

Answer (score 7):

Not with Disk Utility (can't specify custom mount points with Disk Utility) but the macOS installer environment has Terminal. With Terminal, you can run:

```
mount_apfs /dev/disk1s3 /Users
```

Replace disk1s3 with the identifier of the volume to mount there.

This should answer your question about mounting during installation, but after a reboot your disk will be unmounted and /Users unavailable. To permanently set a mount point, [you'll have to mess with fstab](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050805062520199).

Comment: Thanks a lot @grgarside! I tried it today. I added a volume _Users_ then I went into the terminal `mount_apfs /dev/disk1s5 /Users` and I got the following error message: `/Users: No such file  or directory`. I tried to create the folder with `mkdir Users' but I got this error message: `Users: Read-only file system`.

Comment: @stevo I guess you’re running that from Terminal in recovery/install environment? In that case, you need to specify your disk: `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users` instead of `/Users` for example